# Return HTML Response and Add Cookie - Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am attempting to return a response header of 'Set-Cookie', while also return a new HTML response by editing CSS. In other words, I am seeking a way to perform both of these actions in one instance (or merge my two IF statements into one):

```
  const country = request.cf.country
  let cookies = request.headers.get('Cookie') || ""
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  let response = await fetch(request);
  response = new Response(response.body, response);

    if (country != 'US' && country !='CA') {
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "new-int-pricing-mode=on;max-age=604800;Path=/");
return response;
}


if (country != 'US' && country !='CA') 
{const response = await fetch(request)

    var html = await response.text()
    
    // Inject scripts
    const customScripts = '<style type="text/css">STYLING HERE</style></body>'
    html = html.replace( /<\/body>/ , customScripts)
    
    // return modified response
       return new Response(html, response)

}
```

Because I am returning a new Response in one, and only "response" in another - so far all of my "merge" techniques are failing. Is this possible?

I have managed to 99% merge through the use of the cookies. But on first page load, the styling will not take effect (due to the need to apply the cookie)

```
    if ((country != 'US' && country !='CA') && !(cookies.includes("pricing-mode=on"))) {
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "pricing-mode=on;max-age=604800;Path=/");
return response;
}

    else if ((country != 'US' && country !='CA') && (cookies.includes("pricing-mode=on"))) {

    const response = await fetch(request)

    var html = await response.text()
    
    // Inject scripts
    const customScripts = '<style type="text/css">STYLE HERE</style></body>'
    html = html.replace( /<\/body>/ , customScripts)
    
    // return modified response
       return new Response(html, response)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new response object.
https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/modify-response/

```
  const originalResponse = await fetch(request);

  // Change status and statusText, but preserve body and headers
  let response = new Response(originalResponse.body, {
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'some message',
    headers: originalResponse.headers,
  });
```

You can add headers to this response using
`response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "pricing-mode=on;max-age=604800;Path=/");`

Comment: Can you demo how this would incorporate into what I currently have written. Right now, I have decided to run the styling with an enqued CSS file inside of php in order to get these to operate at the same time. Would love to migrate back to cloudflare workers